# How to get width of div while its content isn't yet called - with .html()

Tags: jquery, dom, text, width, not-exists

I saw similar or identical questions but none of these allow me to solve my issue.
I read that a bug exist using .html() and finding div width !

Inside an registration form I call errors with jquery from php .
So I use `html()` function to call error message in ajax/json.
The div containing error is empty before I submit the form.
This div hasn't width property in css and I want use the width of div or text.lenght to position it to the right of inputs form.
By default the text message display on a single line. I can't well position my div whithout getting the width div!

When I use this function :

```
$('.error_form_message').each(function(){       
    var messWidth = $(this).width();
    $(this).css({'width':messWidth}); 
});
```

I get a null width ( precisely I get 20px because of padding ).
Is there a solution?

If the div already have a width property I no longer have a problem but that's not what I want .

Here is the actual problem
[Registration form message error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HW4Uy.png)

Comment: The issue you're trying to solve here isn't clear. If you could add a working example of the problem to the question, including all relevant HTML, JS and CSS, it may help. However, I can say that getting the width of an element then setting the width to the same value will do absolutely nothing - even if you were getting the right `width()` value.

Comment: *or text.length* - in the same way, you don't have the text yet, so you can't use text.length.  You need to set the content so that it has a width (then you don't need to set the width).

Comment: Alternatively, this looks like an XY problem where the actual question is how to make a div appear to the right of the form.  Something like `float:right` or just div-wrapping might work.

Comment: *I can't well position my div without the width* - you can easily position anything without a width.  Most things are positioned without a width.  Try `style='position:relative;right:0'` to align it to the right.

Comment: Thank you all. I solved my error : My previous jquery script wasn't set inside success function. rookie mistake. and effectively I needed only right property : `$(this).css({'right':messWidth}); `